# Sort Address Column Alphabetically Instead of Numerically With Datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am using jquery.dataTables.js to create a table, and one the columns is addresses.

I would like to be able to sort the addresses by the street name instead of by the number.

I tried to override the default sorting like so:

```
       jQuery.extend(jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, {
        "num-html-pre": function (a) {
            var x = String(a).replace(/<[\\s\\S]*?>/g, "");
            return parseFloat(x);
        },

        "num-html-asc": function (a, b) {
            return ((a < b) ? -1 : ((a > b) ? 1 : 0));
        },

        "num-html-desc": function (a, b) {
            return ((a < b) ? 1 : ((a > b) ? -1 : 0));
        }
    });

    var table = $('#addresses').DataTable({
        "order": [[0, "asc"]]
        , "aoColumns": [{ "sType": "num-html", "aTargets": [0] }, { "sType": "numbercase" }, null, { "sType": "numbercase" }, null, { "sType": "numbercase" }]
    });
```

This half works.

It paginates at 10 records per page, and usually returns 200-300 records, so 20-30 pages. The code will sort the address (row[0]) alphabetically, but only for the 10 records on the current page, not the entire record set.

Also, it breaks the functionality where you can click on the column heading to switch between asc/desc.

Little help?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, I needed to drop the parsefloat(x) in the num-html-pre function. Here's what it looks like now:

```
        "num-html-pre": function (a) {
            var x = String(a).replace(/<[\\s\\S]*?>/g, "").replace("&nbsp;", "");
            var y = x.split(' ');
            return y[1];
        },
```